# jhipster registry v5 unable to get loggers

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

Unable to get the loggers and change log level for service that register into registry.

1. Pull and start the jhipster-registry v5.0.1 from docker hub.
2. Use the jhipster CLI v6.0.1 to generate a Microservice gateway project and register into jhipster-registry v5.0.1.
3. Login jhipster-registry, goto the menu Administration > Loggers, select the gateway microservices from drop down, the screen didn't reflect the proper logger result and it unable to change the log level also.

jhipster-registry logs was showing it try to call the rest url `management/logs` which suppose is `management/loggers`?

```
2019-06-03 09:20:56.458 DEBUG 1 --- [ XNIO-1 task-27] i.g.j.r.f.a.AccessControlFilter          : /services/mygateway/mygateway:190b702ae2370a2a35bdc1b56ab6d131/management/logs
2019-06-03 09:20:56.459 DEBUG 1 --- [ XNIO-1 task-27] i.g.j.r.f.a.AccessControlFilter          : Access Control: allowing access for /services/mygateway/mygateway:190b702ae2370a2a35bdc1b56ab6d131/management/logs, as no access control policy has been set up for service: mygateway:190b702ae2370a2a35bdc1b56ab6d131
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve with [jhipster-registry 5.0.2](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/issues/363)